# Setup phpMyAdmin on CentOS VirtualBox

Tags: centos, setup, phpmyadmin

I installed phpMyAdmin from sourceforge, following [this](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-centos-6-2-server/) tutorial.

However, when I login, I see this notice:

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured,
>   some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click
>   here.

The inactive features are here:
http://screencast.com/t/9B01cZ8oT577

For someone who's never configured a server before, what should my next steps be?

I also thought about installing phpmyadmin with certificates to encrypt the data but I'm not sure if this is necessary. If I can simply get my WordPress installation on the server, I figure that's a good first step.

Comment: The screenshot explains exactly wht you need to do, each of those "Documentation" links takes you to the correct part of the documentation, there is even a "Quick steps" section at the bottom explaining what you need to do next.

Comment: I have update the configuration on How to Install phpMyAdmin on CentOS 6.2 Server. I hope this may helps : http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-centos-6-2-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the quick steps at the bottom of the page included in your screenshot:

- Create the needed table with the script/create_tables.sql
- Create the pma user and give access to these tables.
- Enable advanced features in configuration file (config.inc.php) for example by starting from config.sample.inc.php
- Re-login to phpMyAdmin to load the updated configuration file

If you need further help the "Documentation" links explain what you need to know in more detail.